# Bootstrap steps with line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to make something like STEPS in bootstrap. I know that on http://getbootstrap.com/ there is section with progress bars like this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

but i need something like this:

[image]

I know how to make links but how to make this line with inline links?

```
<div class="steps-form">
  <span class="label">ORDER</span>
  <span class="label">PAYMENT</span>
  <span class="label">HAPPINES</span>
</div>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Can you put in your code for the LINE `ORDER - PAYMENT - HAPPINESS`?

Comment: I added and refresh the subject:)

Comment: You may find [this link](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/simplesteps) useful.

Comment: Look for [examples](http://bootply.com/tagged/steps)

Comment: THANKS a lot, that was usefull I made it:)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 new-steps-form">
    <div class="col-md-4"> <h1 class=""><span class="" id="krok1">Order</span></h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> <h1 class="heading-1"><span class="" id="krok2">Payment</span></h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> <h1 class=""><span class="" id="krok3">Happines</span></h1></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
   .new-steps-form h1{
    font-size: 15px !important;
    color:#bdc3c7 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.new-steps-form .heading-1{
    position:relative;
    text-align: center
    display:inline;
}
.new-steps-form .heading-1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 2px #bebebe;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.new-steps-form .heading-1 span {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    padding: 0 20px !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```